# Creating and wiring related instances at runtime with CDI

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-weld

I have a `Service` in a Java SE application (without any application server) which creates `Algorithm` instances and run them.

- Every `Algorithm` instance needs a new (separate) `ActionExecutor` and a new (separate) `AlgorithmState`.
- `ActionExecutor` also needs an `AlgorithmState` instance and this instance have to be the same as `Algorithm` gets.

How can I achieve this with CDI? I've tried constructor injection and `@New` on both parameters of `Algorithm` but I guess this is not what I want.

`Service` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Service {

    @Inject
    private Instance<Algorithm> algorithmInstance;

    public void run() {
        final List<Algorithm> algorithms = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            final Algorithm algorithm = algorithmInstance.get();
            algorithms.add(algorithm);
        }

        for (final Algorithm algorithm: algorithms) {
            algorithm.doSomething();
        }
    }

}
```

`Algorithm` class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.enterprise.inject.New;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Algorithm {

    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(100);

    private final ActionExecutor actionExecutor;
    private final AlgorithmState algorithmState;

    private final int id;

    @Inject
    public Algorithm(@New final ActionExecutor actionExecutor, @New final AlgorithmState algorithmState) {
        this.actionExecutor = actionExecutor;
        this.algorithmState = algorithmState;
        id = counter.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println("algorithm ctor#" + id);
    }

    public void doSomething() {
            System.out.printf("do something, algorithm id: #%d: executor id%sd, stateId: %d, executor->stateId: %d%n", id,
            actionExecutor.getId(), algorithmState.getId(), actionExecutor.getAlgorithmStateId());
    }
}
```

`ActionExecutor` class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class ActionExecutor {

    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(200);

    private final AlgorithmState algorithmState;

    private final int id;

    @Inject
    public ActionExecutor(final AlgorithmState algorithmState) {
        this.algorithmState = algorithmState;
        id = counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getAlgorithmStateId() {
        return algorithmState.getId();
    }
}
```

`AlgorithmState` class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class AlgorithmState {

    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(300);

    private final int id;

    @Inject
    public AlgorithmState() {
        id = counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("state start#" + id);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And a `ServiceMain` class for testing:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.bindings.Parameters;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.events.ContainerInitialized;

public class ServiceMain {

    @Inject
    private Service service;

    public void printHello(
            @Observes final ContainerInitialized event,
            @Parameters final List<String> parameters) {
        System.out.println("ServiceMain:" + service);
        service.run();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain.main(args);
    }

}
```

Currently it prints the following:

```
do something, algorithm id: #101: executor id201d, stateId: 302, executor->stateId: 301
do something, algorithm id: #102: executor id202d, stateId: 304, executor->stateId: 303
do something, algorithm id: #103: executor id203d, stateId: 306, executor->stateId: 305
```

What I need is that the `stateId` and `executor->stateId` are the same:

```
do something, algorithm id: #101: executor id201d, stateId: 301, executor->stateId: 301
do something, algorithm id: #102: executor id202d, stateId: 302, executor->stateId: 302
do something, algorithm id: #103: executor id203d, stateId: 303, executor->stateId: 303
```

**edit:**

Currently I'm getting the `AlgorithmState` from the `AlgorithmExecutor` but it messes up the model, I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Not familiar with CDI-SE. But for EE these problems are solved with scopes and qualifiers.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the `@New` qualifier was replaced with the `@Dependant` scope, which is the default scope anyway. I'd imagine it was changed in CDI 1.1 due to the confusion that it causes. Plus, `@New` is a qualifier, not a scope, and is from a separate standard that can be used for multiple purposes (I don't think `@New` is really used by any standards).

It looks like you'd want to use `@Produces` in `AlgorithmState` instead of `@Inject`. Check out the [Weld documentation on the subject](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/producermethods.html) for some more details. You might want to create a specific [scoped type](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html) like so:

```
@ScopeType
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR})
public @interface AlgorithmScoped {}
```

Then you could modify the `AlgorithmState` constructor:

```
@Produces @AlgorithmScoped
public AlgorithmState() {
    // ...
}
```

Add that scope to `AlgorithmExecutor`, and then also to `Algorithm`. I don't think you should be trying to inject `AlgorithmState` into `Algorithm`; get that from the `AlgorithmExecutor` instance! In fact, if you do that, that should solve the entire problem in a nutshell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've seen the custom scope but it needs a custom `Context` object which looks to complicated. I guess I would be happy with simple example but I haven't seen any simple ones yet. (I've updated the question too.)

Comment: Have you looked at [javax.enterprise.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/package-summary.html)? More details about the context of your problem might help (e.g., are you just using Weld on its own? or are you using a full Java EE environment? or is it like Tomcat + libraries?).

Comment: It's and old Java SE application with a `main` method (which calls Weld's `main` method). We don't have any appserver nor Tomcat. I haven't seen `javax.enterprise.concurrent` yet. Would it help?

Comment: Well, if it's not in an application server, there's no need to use managed concurrency. You could just use `java.util.concurrent` instead to get real executors and such which could help your architecture.

Comment: I guess you mean `AlgorithmExecutor`. It uses a `ThreadPool` internally but its responsibility is to collect some diagnostic data about the submitted tasks. (We have other similar use-cases in the application when we have to wire a group of objects runtime.)

Comment: It might be the case that you can't `@Inject` the state into the executor if you want to inject them both into the algorithm. This could actually be a design limitation of the current CDI spec. Have you tried injecting the state into the executor as a method instead of a constructor? Avoid constructors tends to help a lot in beans.

Comment: Calling setters works, I've created a PoC for that and I've played with custom scope/context as well but both requires some more work.

Comment: @New is a perfectly valid CDI annotation, typically used in CDI producers as a parameter annotation to indicate that the producer produces a new instance each time.